# ASP.NET C# Personality Test

Tags: c#, asp.net

I thought that my code for this personality test in ASP.NET using C# was fine. But sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. I'm not getting any syntax errors, and like I said, sometimes it works perfectly. Is there a logic error that I'm missing?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Debug="true" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<script runat="server"> 

public int m_score = 0;
public int m_imageScore = 0;


//Displaying the autopostback message for the selection of the workList drop-down list
protected void workListChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{
    if (workList.SelectedItem.Text == "Office Work")
        lblWork.Text = "You prefer to stay inside and code your life away.";
    else if (workList.SelectedItem.Text == "Outdoor Work")
        lblWork.Text = "You enjoy the great outdoors.";
    else if (workList.SelectedItem.Text == "Investigative Work")
        lblWork.Text = "OK, Sherlock.";
    else if (workList.SelectedItem.Text == "Working With People")
        lblWork.Text = "As opposed to extraterrestirals?";
    else if (workList.SelectedItem.Text == "Work Requiring Travel")
        lblWork.Text = "I can show you the world . . . ";
    else if (workList.SelectedItem.Text == "Helping People")
        lblWork.Text = "You're a noble spirit.";
}  


//Finding the score for the which part of the image the user clicked
 public void ImageButton_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{

    if ((e.X > 2 && e.X < 87) && (e.Y > 2 && e.Y < 120))
        m_imageScore = 50;
    else if ((e.X > 96 && e.X < 212) && (e.Y > 1 && e.Y < 89))
        m_imageScore = 25;
    else if ((e.X > 2 && e.X < 87) && (e.Y > 121 && e.Y < 211))
        m_imageScore = 10;
    else if ((e.X > 124 && e.X < 212) && (e.Y > 94 && e.Y < 218))
        m_imageScore = 5;

}

//Finding score for Checkbox List
 public void CheckBoxList(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     foreach (ListItem item in CheckBoxlist1.Items)
         if (item.Selected)
         {
             m_score = Int32.Parse(item.Value) + m_score;
         }
 }

 //Finding score for the remaining lists
 public void ButtonClick1(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    m_score = textComments.Text.Length + m_score;
    m_score = Int32.Parse(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value) + m_score;
    m_score = Int32.Parse(RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Value) + m_score;
    m_score = Int32.Parse(workList.SelectedItem.Value) + m_score;

    int final_score = m_score + m_imageScore;
    if (final_score > 100)
        lblresults.Text = "You are an outgoing personality type.";
    else if (final_score > 100 && final_score <50)
        lblresults.Text = "You are a merry soul.";
    else if (final_score < 50 && final_score > 25)
        lblresults.Text = "You are a regular kind of all-around person.";
    else if (final_score <25 && final_score > 0)
        lblresults.Text = "You are a shy one, aren't you?";

 }








</script>

<html>
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title>Personality Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:Label id="lblName"
        Text="Name"
        AssociatedControlID="txtName"
        runat="server" />

    <asp:TextBox
        id="txtname"
        AutoPostBack="true"
        runat="server" />

    <br /><br />

    <asp:TextBox
        id="textComments"
        Text="Tell me a little about yourself"
        TextMode="MultiLine"
        Columns="30"
        rows="10"
        runat="server" />
    <br /><br />

    <strong>Select a gender:</strong>
    <asp:RadioButton
        id="rd1Male"
        Text="Male"
        GroupName="rgGender"
        runat="server" />

    <asp:RadioButton
        id="rd1Female"
        Text="Female"
        GroupName="rgGender"
        runat="server" />
    <br /><br />


    <strong>Favorite Season:</strong>
    <br />
     <asp:DropDownList
         id="DropDownList1"
         Runat="server"
         AutoPostBack="true"
         >
    <asp:ListItem value="15">Spring</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem value="10">Summer</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem value="20">Fall</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem value="5">Winter</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <br /><br />


    <strong>Which of the following colors are your favorite?</strong>
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Value="3">Red</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="4">Blue</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="7">Purple</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="5">Yellow</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="6">Green</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="2">Orange</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="8">Violet</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="9">Pink</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="10">Brown</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="0">Grey</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>

    <br /><br />
    <strong>Which type of work do you prefer?</strong>
    <br />
      <asp:DropDownList
         id="workList"
         Runat="server"
         AutoPostBack="true"
         OnSelectedIndexChanged="workListChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Value="3">Office Work</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem value="2">Outdoor Work</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem value="7">Investigative Work</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem value="6">Woring With People</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem value="5">Work Requiring Travel</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem value="4">Helping Others</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <br />

    <asp:Label
        id="lblWork"
        runat ="server" />
    <br /><br />


    <strong>Which foods do you like (check as many as you want)</strong>
    <asp:CheckBoxList 
    id="CheckBoxlist1" 
    runat="server" 
    RepeatColumns="6"
     RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
     TextAlign="Right">
    <asp:ListItem value="13">Bread</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem value="14">Carrots</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem value="1">Ice Cream</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem value="2">Potato Chips</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem value="5">Candy Bars</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem value="7">Cheesecake</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem value="16">Steak</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem value="9">Soft Drinks</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem value="15">Milk</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem value="11">Spaghetti</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem value="11">Pizza</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem value="17">Cheese</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem value="15">Almonds</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem value="3">Brownies</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem value="13">Apples</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem value="14">Oranges</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem value="15">Melons</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem value="14">Peas</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem value="19">Brussel Sprouts</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem value="15">Salads</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem value="14">Tuna Fish</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:CheckBoxList>
    <br /><br />
    <strong>Which picture most appeals to you?</strong>
    <br />
    <asp:ImageButton
        id="imgChoice"
        imageURL="PersTest.jpg"
        runat="server"
        OnClick="ImageButton_Click" />
    <br /><br /><br /><br />

    <asp:Button
        id="btnPersonality"
        Text="Submit Personality"
        runat="server" 
        OnClick="ButtonClick1"/>
    <br /><br />

    <asp:Label
        id="lblresults"
        runat="server" />



</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What doesn't work about it? "Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't" gives us neither enough information about what's supposed to happen nor how that fails to occur.

Comment: Please define "sometimes it doesn't".

Comment: It is impossible for us to know if there is a logic error, if we do not know the logic you're using. We have neither the inputs or expected outputs, simply a way too big block of code. I'd encourage you to set a breakpoint and debug manually your corner cases to know what's going on.

Comment: Maybe the personality you are trying to test is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using your if statements for determining the selected item, try using a switch. That will give you more control as you can have multiple cases fall through and set a default.

Your main problem I think is going to come from your scoring. Look at your second score check:

```
else if (final_score > 100 && final_score <50)
```

Notice something? You're testing to see if it's greater than 100 and less than 50. I think you have the two backwards here. What happens though if it's equal to 100? All your cases are greater than, or less than, but none take into account an equal match so you end up with holes. What happens if it's 50? Nothing. What happens if it's 0? Nothing in these cases. You might want to try something like:

```
if (final_score > 100)
    lblresults.Text = "You are an outgoing personality type.";
else if (final_score <= 100 && final_score > 50)
    lblresults.Text = "You are a merry soul.";
else if (final_score <= 50 && final_score > 25)
    lblresults.Text = "You are a regular kind of all-around person.";
else if (final_score <= 25 && final_score >= 0)
    lblresults.Text = "You are a shy one, aren't you?";
```

Comment: This was it. I had my limits mixed up. Thank you for also pointing out the fact that I hadn't covered the greater or equal to/less than equal to numbers. HUGE help! Thanks!